# javascript - How to move an img tag into a div without reloading the image?

Tags: javascript

```
const div = document.createElement('div');
const span = document.createElement('span');
const img = document.querySelector('img');
const imgCloned = img.cloneNode();
div.appendChild(imgCloned);
div.append(span);
img.replaceWith(div);
```

It is working and the `img` is being moved into the `div` element, however, because it is a cloned image, there is another request to get the image. How can I move the `img` into the `div` without reloading the image?

Comment: don't clone it, just append it - hmm, maybe not

Comment: A new request for the same image should generally only make it as far as the browser cache anyway, so most of the time this won't have any noticeable effect on performance.

Comment: @JaromandaX Have you ever tested it? It returns `Uncaught DOMException: Element.replaceWith: The new child is an ancestor of the parent` in firefox and `Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'replaceWith' on 'Element': The new child element contains the parent. at HTMLBodyElement` in chrome.

Comment: @DBS However, I prefer not to load that even from the cache.

Comment: @kodfire - that's why I said "maybe not" ... because you're basically just trying to wrap an existing image inside a div with an added span

Comment: how about something simple like this : https://code-boxx.com/move-html-element-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

re-order what you're doing

replace the image and then add the image to the beginning of the div

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
const span = document.createElement('span');
const img = document.querySelector('img');
div.append(span);
img.replaceWith(div);
div.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', img);
```

```html
<div>
  The image is here
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/200/300">
  <span> other things live here </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Just *move* it to the created div ...

This little [stackblitz project](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-44kcus?file=script.js) has a function to move an image, fork it to play with the code.

```js
const div = document.createElement('div');
const span = document.createElement('span');
div.append(document.querySelector('img'));
div.append(span);
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
document.querySelector(`pre`).textContent = 
  document.body.querySelector(`div`).outerHTML;
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300">
<h3>Your html after move</h3>
<pre></pre>
```

Comment: This works ... only if the image is the only thing in the DOM - or at the the root of body

Comment: Sure, it's an example (a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)). OP can modify this ofcourse to use for his own code.

Comment: sure, good effort